# emberjs app using apache and php with sub directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ember.js

I have an ember application running on apache/php

Here are my routes:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('homes');
    this.route('rentals');
    this.route('about');
    this.route('contact');
    this.resource('account',function(){
        this.route('profile');
        this.route('users');
        this.route('post');
    });
});
```

And here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php#$1 [L]
```

Clicking on my navigation to go to account and then clicking on the sub nav to go to profile works just fine:

mydomain.loc/account/profile

However, when I click reload on that url, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

I'm guessing because my .htaccess is not configured right to do subdirectories with emberjs correctly?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution... the reason for the error is that the paths in the script tags were relative.  For example:  js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js   the fix was simply to change it to:  /js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js